# How to find the IP address of a CCTV camera connected to laptop via ethernet

Tags: linux, nmap, cctv

I'm trying to get the IP address of a CCTV camera and so far had no luck.

The device it's a Hikvision DS-2CD2042WD-I

I have connected it to a PoE switch, which is then connected to my laptop(Ubuntu 18.04)

I want to find the address to that I can rstp to check if the camera works correctly.

My understanding is that these cameras often come on a different interface (i.e 192.0.0.*) and that we need to be on the same interface in order to be able to scan their ip address

There's a tool called SADP that does the job but it's not working on linux for me
I'd like to know if I can achieve the same results using linux command lines

Is there a way to find what network interface the camera is on, find the ip address, change the ip address to be on the same network interface as all of my other devices?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One method is passive; use a packet capture tool such as Wireshark or `tcpdump` to see if you can see the device communicating on the network.

If that fails, try [netdiscover](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/netdiscover.8.html), which can actively sweep all subnets to find devices.